# Deploying google app engine in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio

I am trying to follow the tutorial on https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/app_engine/run_test_deploy. When I try and do the "Deploying Backends" part I get the following error in AS:

Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=chdryra-reviewer&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'chdryra-reviewer').

This application does exist of course in the google developer console but when I go to https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine?project=chdryra-reviewer I get the following error:

This operation is not possible because no App Engine application was found for this project.

Any insight on what I may be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Riz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting on Google Cloud Platform Support I found out my project was created using an old deprecated system as an "API project" (I created it 2 years ago) which doesn't allow Cloud integration. I had to delete it and create a new one. This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial and sample app instead: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints

I found it much more helpful.

Also, if you cannot see your project in the Google Developers Console, then I am sorry to say you cannot upload your project! For help, take a look at this great series of tutorials for Android Studio and Cloud Endpoints (because that is what I deduce you are using) on how to set all that up and get rolling with GAE + Cloud Endpoints!:

http://rominirani.com/2014/01/10/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-1/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My project was in the Google Developers Console. It turns out it was created using an old deprecated system as an "API project" which doesn't allow Cloud integration. I had to delete it and create a new one.